# How to find two equivalent cyclic subgroups in an external direct product

Tags: abstract-algebra

The problem I'm working on is: find all subgroups of order 4 in Z4⊕Z4.
I have recognized several cyclic subgroups; for example, <(0,1)> is an order 4 subgroup.  However, <(0,1)>=<(0,3)>, so they are not two distinct possibilities.  I am having trouble visualizing why they are equal.  (I struggle with cyclic groups in general!)
I also know I need to consider subgroups that are isomorphic to Z4⊕Z4.  How do I find these?